# How to compare each value returned by web_reg_save_param function with another parameter in Load Runner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am working on Load Runner 12.53. I have one web_reg_save_param function with ORDINAL as below:
web_reg_save_param("paramname","LB=","RB=","ORDINAL=ALL",LAST);
 It will return some vales lets say my parameter name is ID and I will get values like ID_1, ID_2,...etc Now I have one more parameter (Say X).

Can you please tell me how can I compare X with ID's. Like
`if(ID_3 == X) {
//Some code
}`

I have to print the ID value which is equals to parameter X.

Here ID_Count is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

see C function **strcmp()** and loadrunner function **lr_eval_string()**

Answer (score 1):

```
//Instantiate variable b at beginning
int b;
//Regular expression
web_reg_save_param("paramname","LB=","RB=","ORDINAL=ALL",LAST); 

//Enter below code after the regular expression

    for(b=1;b<=atoi(lr_eval_string("{paramname_count}"));b++){
        sprintf(value,"{paramname_%d}",b);
        if(strcmp(lr_eval_string("{X}"),lr_eval_string(value)) == 0){
           //Action you need to perform
            }
        }
```